# RoR- Check whether an input is a MD5 hash or Not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, md5

How can I check whether an input string is in the form of a Md5 hash or not in Rails3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider all 32-digit long hexadecimal numbers (ie. consisting solely of letters a-f and digits 0-9) to be md5 hashes.

I don't know if md5's codomain is the whole space of 32-digit long hexadecimals, but a hash should ideally satisfy the condition so you may just assume it is.